# AC^2 Algebraic simplifications

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose I know that:

$AB^2=DF^2+CF^2$;
$AD^2=BE^2+CE^2$;
$AC^2=AE^2+CE^2$;
$AC^2=AF^2+CF^2$

And also: 
$DF=AF-AD$ and $BE=AE-AB$

How can I prove that $AB * AE + AD * AF = AC^2$?

I start like this, but then I get stucked:

$AB*AE + AD*AF = AB*(BE+AB) + AD*(DF+AD) =
AB*BE + AB^2 + AD*DF + AD^2 =
AB*BE + AB^2 + AD*DF + BE^2 + CE^2 =
(AE - BE)*BE + AB^2 + AD*DF + BE^2 + CE^2 =
AE*BE - BE^2 + AB^2 + AD*DF + BE^2 + CE^2 =
AE*BE + AB^2 + AD*DF + CE^2 =
AE*(AE - AB) + AB^2 + AD*DF + CE^2 =
AE^2 - AE*AB + AB^2 + AD*DF + CE^2...$

Can anyone give a hint how to continue?

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $AB=x$, $BE=y$, $AD=p$, $DF=q$, now from the first $4$ equations we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
p^2+(x+y)^2=y^2+CE^2+(x+y)^2=y^2+AC^2 \\=y^2+(p+q)^2+CF^2=y^2+p^2+2pq+x^2
\end{eqnarray*}
and so $xy=pq$.

Now
\begin{eqnarray*}
AB \times AE+ AD \times AF = x(x+y)+p(p+q)
\end{eqnarray*}
and 
\begin{eqnarray*}
AC^2 = (x+y)^2+CE^2=(x+y)^2+p^2-y^2
\end{eqnarray*}
and thus $\color{red}{AB \times AE+ AD \times AF =AC^2}$.

Comment: Thanks! That was a tricky one for me, but your response was really helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

The situation described in the question is of a parallelogram $ABCD$ with obtuse angles at $B,D$. Construct a circle with diameter $AC$. Extend side $AB$ from $A$ to the circle intersecting at $E.\;$ Extend side $AD\;$ fom $A$ to the circle intersecting at $F.\;$ The segment $AF$ is a chord of the circle. Draw another chord $CG$ from $C$ parallel to segment $AE.\;$So $\;CD\!=\!AB, DG\!=\!BE, AD\!=\!BC$.

The [Intersecting chords theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem) gives $AD\cdot DF=CD\cdot DG.\;$
Now $AD\cdot DF=AB\cdot BE.\;$
Let $\;t:=\cos(\pi-\angle B).\;$ 
By the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), $\;AC^2 =  AB^2 + BC^2 + 2AB\cdot BC\cdot t.\;$ 
Also, by using trigonometry of cosine, $\;t\cdot BC=BE\;$ and $\;t\cdot CD=DF.\;$
Use algebra to calculate
$$AB\!\cdot\!AE\!+\!AD\!\cdot\! AF\!=
\!AB\!\cdot\!(AB\!+\!BE)\!+\!BC\!\cdot\!(BC\!+\!DF)\!=
\!AB^2\!+\!BC^2\!+\!AB\!\cdot\!BE\!+\!BC\!\cdot\!DF.$$
We are now done since $\;AB \cdot BC \cdot t=AB\cdot BE=BC\cdot DF.$ This Euclidean geometry result is somewhat similar to [Ptolemy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy's_theorem) about sum of products of sides of a cyclic quadrilateral.